# In what circumstances will OleDbDataReader.Read() throw?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledbdatareader

What kind of things would make OleDbDataReader.Read() throw an exception after OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader() has run successfully?

```
    public void ReadSomeData(OleDbDataReader reader)
    {
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Do something cool with my precious data
                }
                catch (Exception innerException)
                {
                    // I know what kind of errors I'll catch here
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception outerException)
        {
            // What kind of errors would I expect to catch here?
        }
    }
```

Is there anything, other than calling reader.Close(), which might cause reader.Read() to run successfully the first time through this loop but throw on a later iteration?

(As an experiment, I tried stopping the database via the right click menu in the Object Explorer pane of SQL Management Studio after the call to ExecuteReader() and that didn't seem to stop Read() from working)

Comment: `reader` is null or else the connection is closed or not available

Comment: I think that there is some kind of buffer on the reader so you need to test this closing with a very large dataset

Comment: `DataReader` is read only & forward-only stream (details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders), it stored results data after successfully executing query in the network buffer. Seems that timing to throw exception is when enumerating empty results (possible for NRE), the network buffer is not available or used up too much memory for large data (OutOfMemoryException).